# How to fix the contact form encoding? Sending Thai Language using the contact form

Tags: php, email, contact-form

My problem is that when sending Thai language using the contact form the encoding becomes very weird when I receive the email. But it doesn't happen with English.
Normally, Thai uses TIS-620 encoding for the website, so I also put this  in the header of the page.

This is the email I receive using the contact form:

> Name: א×�°��·�ל ����·��¹¹·ל Email: melo6767@hotmail.com Phone:
>   0811234472 Message: ¤��¼���¼י���¹�ל���טב�י� 
>   ב������¨���÷¶��א��ט�§¤ט�ד×י¨ט�� ב��א��ט�§´�ה«¹ל
>   ¤��µי�§¹�´��ה���§ה§÷י�§ µ�´µט�·�§ג·���¾·לה´יא��¤��÷
>   E-mail��¨¨�ה�ט¤ט����´��

I can't figure out what to do, because I don't know anything about PHP.
Please help.

This is my contact form coding

```
  <div class="contactform">
                            <?php
              if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
                $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);

                if (($mailcheck==FALSE) || (!$_REQUEST['name']) || (!$_REQUEST['subject'] || (!$_REQUEST['message']))){
                    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
          $name = $_POST['name'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email = $_POST['email'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['phone'])){
          $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['subject'])){
          $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['message'])){
          $message = $_POST['message'];
        }




        $form = "<div class=\"indent\"><form method=\"post\" action=\"contactus.php?pg=5\">";
                    $form .= "<p class='textred indent'>Name / ชื่อ-นามสกุล * </p>";
                    $form .= "<input name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"".htmlentities($name)."\" />";
                    $form .= "<br />";
                    $form .= "<p class=\"textred indent\">Email / อีเมล * </p>";
                    $form .= "<input name=\"email\" type=\"text\" value=\"".htmlentities($email)."\"/>";
                    $form .= "<br />";
                    $form .= "<p class=\"indent\">Phone / เบอร์โทรศัพท์ </p>";
                    $form .= "<input name=\"phone\" type=\"text\" value = \"".htmlentities($phone)."\" />";
                    $form .= "<br />";
                    $form .= "<p class=\"textred indent\">Subject / หัวข้อ * </p>"; 
                    $form .= "<input name=\"subject\" type=\"text\" value = \"".htmlentities($subject)."\" />";
                    $form .= "<br />";
                    $form .= "<p class=\"textred indent\">Message / ข้อความ * </p>";
                    $form .= "<textarea name='message' rows='17' cols='46'>".htmlentities($message)."</textarea><br />";
        $form .= "<img src=\"captcha.php\" id=\"captcha\" /><br/>
        <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"
          document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
          document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();\"
          id=\"change-image\"><p style='font-size:12px;'>Change text.</p></a><br/>
        <p class='textred indent'>Enter code above*</p>  
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"captcha\" id=\"captcha-form\" autocomplete=\"off\" /><br/>
          <input type='submit' />
                    </form> <p class='textred'>*Please provide the necessary details. กรุณาใส่ข้อมูลให้ถูกต้อง</p></div>";


        echo $form;

                }else{

                  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
                  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
                  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ; 
                  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
                  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

                  $toEmail = 'info@culfix.com';
                  $messageBody = "Name: ". $_REQUEST['name']. "\n";
                  $messageBody .="Email: ". $_REQUEST['email']. "\n";
                  $messageBody .="Phone: ". $_REQUEST['phone']. "\n";
                  $messageBody .="Message: ". $_REQUEST['message']. "\n";
                  $mailHeader = "From: ". $_REQUEST['email']."\r\n";
                  $mailHeader .= "Reply-To: ". $_REQUEST['email']."\r\n";


                  mail($toEmail, $subject, $messageBody, $mailHeader);
                  header("Location:email.php?pg=5");
                  ob_end_finish();
                }
              }else{
                echo "<div class=\"indent\">
                <form method='post' action='contactus.php?pg=5'>
                    <p class=\"indent\">Name / ชื่อ-นามสกุล * </p>
                    <input name='name' type='text' />
                    <br />
                    <p class=\"indent\">Email / อีเมล * </p>
                    <input name='email' type='text' />
                    <br />
                    <p class=\"indent\">Phone / เบอร์โทรศัพท์ </p>
                    <input name='phone' type='text' />
                    <br />
                    <p class=\"indent\">Subject / หัวข้อ * </p>
                    <input name='subject' type='text' />
                    <br />
                    <p class=\"indent\">Message / ข้อความ *</p>
                    <textarea name='message' rows='17' cols='46'></textarea><br />
        <div class='indent'><img src=\"captcha.php\" id=\"captcha\" /></div>
        <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"
          document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
          document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();\"
          id=\"change-image\"><p style='font-size:12px;'>Change text.</p></a><br/>
          <p class='indent'>Enter code above</p>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"captcha\" id=\"captcha-form\" autocomplete=\"off\" />  <br/>
                    <input type='submit' />
                    </form></div>";
              }
            ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: The problem may not be the form itself, but actually the email. What encoding is the email?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your form's **enctype** attribute `<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8">`.

Instead of "UTF-8", set "TIS-620" and see if that solved your problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can decode the previous mail that I have received so that I can read it??

Comment: It may be possible to decode text that was misencoded, but your text has probably been corrupted by the misencoding. To attempt decoding, you would use a tool like `iconv` to step backwards through each encoding step. That will take trial and error without possibly ever being successful.